# How to determine at runtime whether a tag is valid inside a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I am working on a JS plugin ([Just Show Me The Colors](http://musically-ut.github.io/just-show-me-the-colors/)) which walks a DOM tree (which is not under my control) and replaces certain `TextNodes` with a `span`.

There are certain contexts when this will result in invalid markup, like inside `svg:text` node. However, this code doesn't throw any errors in Chrome/FF:

```
var text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg:text");
text.appendChild(document.craeteElement("span"));
```

even though it is invalid markup.

Similarly, putting a `div` inside a `p` is allowed but *works* (TM).

However, putting a `span` inside a `script` tag is also allowed but does not *work*.

Is there a way I can determine at runtime whether the markup I am generating is valid or will *work* or not?

Comment: Why not simply use a list of valid parents ([those that can contain phrasing elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to keep a list of elements which can validly contain a span.

Here's a list : http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/span/html5_span_tag_nested.php

Answer (score 1):

You can do this only by using a list (well, array) of element names that are allowed inside a given element, according to the definition that you wish to adhere to. Browsers have no understanding of such issues. There are several different definitions for HTML, and they have different content models for elements.

Whether things “work” is a different issue. You should specify a much more concrete question, including a description of what you expect or wish to happen; “works” is not a description.

In particular, note that `span` is not valid inside `script`, and no `script` element created by normal HTML (or XHTML) parsing contains any `span` element (or any other element for that matter). If you create a `script` containing a `span`, the consequences depend on what the browser does with `script` elements, i.e. how they find the content that they will then parse and interpret as script code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think browsers do have to understand to some extent which elements are allowed where because they have the responsibility of rendering them. I was hoping that a browser would have some sort of an alarm to tell me that the DOM I am inserting will lead to unpredictable behavior but having an exhaustive list seems the way to go.